# Is there any other method to write these?

Tags: python

How to rewrite these using def or others, I don't quite know what does [None] mean here.

```
 imgs = [None]*N_VERSIONS

 for i in range(N_VERSIONS):

     imgs[i] = io.imread(pathname + '_' + str(i) + '.' + ext)
```

Comment: Lets substitute `N_VERSIONS` with 4. Then printing `imgs` will give you `[None, None, None, None]`

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[None]` is a list containing the element `None`.  You don't need to initialize a list with empty values before filling it, though.  Just do:

```
imgs = [io.imread(pathname + '_' + str(i) + '.' + ext) for i in range(N_VERSIONS)]
```

Comment: `f'{pathname}_{i}.{ext}'` would be much simpler.

Comment: @chepner Even better, use pathlib ;)

Answer (score 0):

The None keyword is used to define a null variable or an object. In Python, None keyword is an object, and it is a data type of the class NoneType. You can write your code into a def like this

`def my_function_name(N_VERSIONS):
    imgs = [None]*N_VERSIONS
    for i in range(N_VERSIONS):
        imgs[i] = io.imread(pathname + '_' + str(i) + '.' + ext)`
but you write in many different ways depending on how you are using.